# TableSearch sample and error: "There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos4.0'"

Tags: iphone, ios4

I downloaded the latest sample code from the Apple developer site and even though I've set the Project settings, I can't build the project.

I have the XCode version 3.2.4 with iOS 4.1 and I get the error:

> There is no SDK with the name or path
>   'iphoneos4.0'

I've changed the value of "Base SDK" to "iOS Device 4.1" found in the Build tab that you get to via "Project" :: "Edit Project Settings" page.

What else should I change to get this project to build? There are no #ifdefs defined to say it can only build on 4.0.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that I had to go to the Targets item from the Groups and Files pane and change the Base SDK there as well. I thought changing it one place would do it in XCode, but alas, not so.